# the asymptotic behavior of solutions to ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have a question about the asymptotic behavior of ode. That is, the limit  of solution $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}x(t)$.

What is its destination? I found in a paper, it says:

"the trajectory converges to either a ﬁxed point, to a (quasi)-periodic orbit, or to a chaotic attractor."

So it seems the asymptotic behavior can be classified as the above three types, is this right? and which theorem can confirm it?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: The solution can also be unbounded.

Comment: Is there a specific ODE you are looking at? What is the dimension? I'm also not sure what you've quoted it right. There are unbounded orbits, but an orbit can also converge to a set composed of fixed points and heteroclinic orbits, which I would not describe as "quasi-periodic" or a "chaotic attractor."

Comment: Thank you both for the prompt reply! @TrevorNorton Actually I think the odes considered in the paper are general 1-order ode, and arbitrary dimension. The paper is here https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11071-021-06786-5

Comment: In the context of the paper, I think that is an assumption they are making about the orbits they are modeling and not a general statement about any solution. If you are in $\mathbb R^2$, then the Poincare-Bendixson theorem can characterize the limit sets. I'm not sure if there are results for $\mathbb R^n$ with $n>2$, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor#Types_of_attractors might give some ideas about possible limit sets.

Comment: Thanks! This clears up my mind. Could I ask a further question? For N-dimensional dynamical systems, if we know there only exist  one stable equilibrium (but whether it is global or local is not yet proved), can we infer, the stable equilibrium is globally stable?

Comment: I’m not sure if I know what you mean by “global” stable equilibrium. Most of the time stability is a strictly local property (if I start close enough to an equilibrium then I will stay close to the equilibrium). If you mean that a stable equilibrium is a global attractor (i.e. all orbits converge to it), then the answer is no for $n>1$. You can have local stability but far away orbits may never approach the equilibrium.